# Nextflow tuple from CSV cols

Tags: nextflow, workflow-management

I am trying to create a channel with a CSV file and use it as tuple input. Yet the output I obtain does not contain the entire file but only the first element of the file (1st row).

**the csv**

```
dig,val 
1,One
2,Two
3,Three
4,Four
5,Five
```

output :
`cat digOne.txt`
`1` 
instead of the whole collection
digOne, digTwo...

```
 size_amp_ch = Channel
        .fromPath( params.file)
        .splitCsv(header:true).map{
            row  -> tuple(row.dig,row.val)
        }

process{
    input:

    tuple val(digits), val(values)
    
    output:


    path "dig_${values}.txt"

    script:

    """
    echo $digits >> dig_${values}.txt


}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is just that you have extra whitespace at the end of the first line in your CSV file. Either remove the whitespace manually, or use the `strip` parameter with the [`splitCsv`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) operator to remove leading and trailing whitespace from values. For example:

```
params.file = './file.csv'


process test_proc {

    input:
    tuple val(digits), val(values)

    output:
    path "dig_${values}.txt"

    """
    echo "${digits}" > "dig_${values}.txt"
    """
}

workflow { 
 
    Channel.fromPath( params.file ) \
        | splitCsv( header:true, strip:true ) \
        | map { row ->
            tuple( row.dig, row.val )
        } \
        | test_proc \
        | view()

}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [stupefied_boyd] DSL2 - revision: 2a9d8dc414
executor >  local (5)
[4f/a73196] process > test_proc (2) [100%] 5 of 5 ✔
/path/to/work/9d/4905d0236788c1a3733da5358b7fc4/dig_Four.txt
/path/to/work/f9/d04e8a1c2265d73cde626703317df7/dig_Five.txt
/path/to/work/ff/522238f87a5641fdc7adce3e4d1cea/dig_Three.txt
/path/to/work/e9/9b7ec2a65d45986fd8944da4a2054c/dig_One.txt
/path/to/work/4f/a73196fbd56db3c9647fa7b072edfd/dig_Two.txt
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the answer, it seems that your answer is not solving my problem, I wonder if my test file is causing this. thank you so much for the help

Comment: @LoïcBorcard So what is the problem exactly? What are you trying to achieve or what are you expecting?